# Select Records with same email in different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to extract all records that has same email in different fields from an email table. I am not sure how to do that in sql. looking for help.[The image has id and email fields. I am trying to extract records which has same email in different fields.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrVFd.png)

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?  Can you provide any examples (in *text*, not an image) of your expected input/output?

Comment: SELECT * FROM email where email in ( SELECT email1 FROM email GROUP BY email1 HAVING count(*) > 1);  This is something that i tried.

Comment: I also Tried doing this: select email1, email2, email3,add1,add2, count(*) occurences from email group by email1, email2, email3,add1,add2 having count(*) > 1

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to compare each email address in a row with every other email address in the same row, taking into account that you don't want to have empty email addresses compare equal.  Here's my suggestion (which I've played around with a bit [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4c3a3/5)):

```
select * from email
where
(email1 <> '' and email1 in (email2, email3, Add1, Add2))
or (email2 <> '' and email2 in (email3, Add1, Add2))
or (email3 <> '' and email3 in (Add1, Add2))
or (Add1 <> '' and Add1 = Add2)
```

Additional note: If you have superfluous spaces tagged on to any emails, you may need to `trim` them all.